# Can still enter the UK using my indefinite leave to remain status although the immigration officer stamped my passport with a Leave to enter

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, passports, visa-refusals, passport-stamps

On May 13, 1983 I was granted a **Leave to Remain** in the UK for an indefinite period visa and since then I have maintained this status by not staying outside the UK for more than two years. During my last visit on July 29, 2018 the border force immigration officer stamped my passport with a **Leave to enter for six months** and not as a returning resident. I am planning to travel back to the UK next month. Do I need a visa or I can still enter the UK using my **indefinite leave to remain status**